# How to convert pandas dataframe date column in format of 'dd/mm/yyyy %H:%M' to 'yyyy/mm/dd %H:%M'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have dataframe in the format of 'dd/mm/yyyy %H:%M'.

```
Date                Price
29/10/2018 19:30    163.09
29/10/2018 20:00    211.95
29/10/2018 20:30    205.86
29/10/2018 21:00    201.39
29/10/2018 21:30    126.68
29/10/2018 22:00    112.36
29/10/2018 22:30    120.94
```

I want this dataframe in the format of 'yyyy/mm/dd %H:%M' as following.

```
Date                Price
2018/29/10 19:30    163.09
2018/29/10 20:00    211.95
2018/29/10 20:30    205.86
2018/29/10 21:00    201.39
2018/29/10 21:30    126.68
2018/29/10 22:00    112.36
2018/29/10 22:30    120.94
```

I tried 
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date])` but it gives result as following which is not something I am looking for

```
Date                   Price
2018-29-10 19:30:00    163.09
2018-29-10 20:00:00    211.95
2018-29-10 20:30:00    205.86
2018-29-10 21:00:00    201.39
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for convert datetimes to string format:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')

print (df)
               Date   Price
0  2018/10/29 19:30  163.09
1  2018/10/29 20:00  211.95
2  2018/10/29 20:30  205.86
3  2018/10/29 21:00  201.39
4  2018/10/29 21:30  126.68
5  2018/10/29 22:00  112.36
6  2018/10/29 22:30  120.94

print (type(df.loc[0, 'Date']))
<class 'str'>

print (df['Date'].dtype)
object
```

So if want working with datetimeslike function, use only `to_datetime`, format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
print (df)
                 Date   Price
0 2018-10-29 19:30:00  163.09
1 2018-10-29 20:00:00  211.95
2 2018-10-29 20:30:00  205.86
3 2018-10-29 21:00:00  201.39
4 2018-10-29 21:30:00  126.68
5 2018-10-29 22:00:00  112.36
6 2018-10-29 22:30:00  120.94

print (type(df.loc[0, 'Date']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

print (df['Date'].dtype)
datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Pandas stores `datetime` as integers

When you say `it gives result as following`, you are only seeing a **string representation** of these underlying integers. You should not misconstrue this as how Pandas stores your data or, indeed, how the data will be represented when you export it to another format.

#### Convert to `object` dtype

You can use [`pd.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to convert your series to a series of strings. This will have `object` dtype, which represents a sequence of pointers:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
```

You will lose all vectorisation benefits, so you should aim to perform this operation only if necessary and as late as possible.